# JavaScript: Update localstorage once at start of the day

Tags: javascript

I need to update localstorage at start of the every day, which will contain a large value populated by an API.

Since the value is large, this needs to be done at once only, preferably at the start of the day when the application is active and then cache the value in localstorage for rest of the day.

I came across setInterval solution which will monitor the clock and will hit API at 12 AM and cache the value in the localstorage. But interval seems costly. Also, it may be possible that the application is not active/running at 12 AM on the client which can miss the API call.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: use cron job for your task

Comment: "Large" how? The LocalStorage can't hold more than 5 MB anyway. Is it gigabyte-large? Are you trying to store an entire database client-side? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually didn't want to hit the API multiple times in a day, since it is designed to return same data for a day.

Comment: Is cron job possible at client side with JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe I think adding a key to localstorage with date as value as validity for the data, will aid in identifying its age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

supposed **data** is returned data from API and you want to save this data into localStorage. Then you can do..

```js
localStorage.data = JSON.stringify({data,current_date});
```

Now, whenever the user visits the site, then check the `current_date` attribute like..

```js
// call this function whenever users visit your site, depending on your tech stack.
const dataDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.data).current_date;
if(dataDate != today_date){
  // load the data
}
```

### solution 2

use cookies with 1 day of expiry. I hope you know, how to use cookies.

```js
// whenever you call API, set cookie with 1 day of expiry value
// when a user visits the site, then check if the cookie is present or not
// if the cookie is not present then load the data.
```